# other subnet CANNOT resolve internal host name but can resovle internet host name

Tags: dns, subnet

Pls help.  I just setup a Bind9 in Ubuntu 20.4 server(192.168.1.100). I have 3 subnet in the network.   192.168.0.0/23, 192.168.33.0/24 and 192.168.88.0/24.

In 192.168.0.0/23 network, I can resolve Internet Host name and Internal host name without problem.

But in 192.168.33.0/24 and 192.168.88.0/24 netowork, I can resolve the Internet Host name such [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).  But I cannot resolve the right IP for the internal host.  When I try to resovle an internal host. It will return the IP 208.91.112.55.

Anyone knows what is the problem?[named.conf.options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z02w.png)
[named.conf.local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2obt.png)
[zone file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkZ2O.png)
[ping restult from other subnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKKzS.png)

Comment: I just dealt with this by setting up an AdGuardHome adblocker.  Since it is not my default DNS, I tried to have external DNS (like 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1) setup on it, but it wouldn't work for any of my local hosts.  I could ping them, but no name resolutions.  So, to fix it, I set its DNS server to my main DNS server (router) and all my problems were solved.